# Callback Delphi function from TWebBrowser by javascript on Delphi XE6 for all platforms (including iOS, ANDROID)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, delphi

I need create an application on Delphi XE6 for Android and iOS.
This application mest be use a TWebBrowser to show Google Maps, then I need "send" from Delphi to javascript and "receive" command from javascript to Delphi. In this way I can show a market on map and then know when the user click on marker.
I have found this [article](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nikolay/2014/04/17/exampleofusingjavascriptforgooglemapsinthedelphixe6/) on web to execute javascript by Delphi code.

But I don't have idea about how can call a delphi procedure from javascript.
For example I have this procedure on Delphi:

```
procedure JSFeekback(aParm1, aParm2, aParm3, aParm4: string);
```

and I want use Javascript code on TWebBrowser to call it an pass 4 parameters.
I have found similar questions but only for Windows application and the answers don't work on Android (I haven't tried on iOS).

Comment: Check this [link](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22) if you have not yet. Although it is done with COM (ergo Windows) it might give you some idea. On the other hand, I also found this link in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/uDxAUTvXqzc), where they speak about how to do it with `TChromium` instead of `TWebBrowser`. Might be worth a look (if `TChromium` can be used for iOS/Android?)

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do it is with the `addJavascriptInterface` function of the Android WebView, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962150/understanding-androids-webview-addjavascriptinterface), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314492/android-using-addjavascriptinterface-to-return-a-value-from-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206363/javascript-not-calling-method-in-android-using-addjavascriptinterface).

The Firemonkey TWebBrowser does not expose this function by default.

There is a custom WebView wrapper control in DPF Android as can be seen [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/).

You could modify that control to add the `addJavascriptInterface` function.

For TWebBrowser on IOS you could use the custom web browser controls in [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/) and  [here](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsicl.asp).

Another possible way to do this is with the `OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` event of TWebBrowser. You could do something like:

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
window.location.href=”#param1&param2&param3&param4”;
</script>
```

or

```
<script language=”javascript”>
window.navigate(”javascript:thisisatest();”);
</script>
```

And see if the URL property of `OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` contains `#param1&param2&param3&param4` or `javascript:thisisatest();`.

Basically the idea is to navigate to a URL that doesn't change the URL of the existing page and pick up that URL in the `OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` event.

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript it is very common to access HTTP servers, for example over jQuery. If you can make your Delphi code available over HTTP, either as a local serveror on the web, your JavaScript code can invoke Delphi code by sending a HTTP request, and receive data from Delphi functions as a HTTP response.

Another option are WebSockets. They are an extension of HTTP, work asynchronously so the Delphi server can send data to the script - without having to wait for a request first (known as server push / Comet).

This would be a standards-based, widely used solution, which does not rely on a particular web client. The free open source library Internet Direct (Indy) can be used on all supported platforms to create HTTP servers, stand-alone or integrated with your application.

Other protocols which are availabe for communication between JavaScript and servers might be also worth a look, for example STOMP.

For your specific function, the HTTP call could use a GET request with parameters:

```
http://localhost/JSFeekback?par1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3&par4=val4
```

Comment: My Delphi code is NOT available over HTTP. I need a solution like comment of @Guillem Vicens but wrking on Android and iOS and I like use the new TWebBrowser on Delphi XE6. I think is TChromium is a bit complicated.

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer, maybe it is helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

`TWebBrowser.URL` can be changed within javascript:

```
window.location.href=”#param1&param2&param3&param4”;
```

then run a timer to check TWebBrowser.URL, get the params, call your JSFeekback, reset the URL.

Or no timer, code like this:

```
  wb1.EvaluateJavaScript("window.location.href=”#param1&param2&param3&param4”;");
  getParams(wb1.URL);
  JSFeekback(p1, p2, p3, p4);
```