# Callback from Firemonkey WebBrowser JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, delphi, firemonkey

How to make call of Firemonkey code (callback) from JavaScript code in TTMSFMXWebBrowser?

I can perform JavaScript code from Firemonkey, but how I can make a callback or call Firemonkey code/event from JavaScript?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the URL you can pass a custom string or whatever data like this:

myurl://dostuff?a=b&c=d

```
if (Copy(S, 1, 8)='myurl://') then
begin
// now you know it is a callback and not a real URL
// if it is a callback you can cancel the load using the below code
// and then process the callback
end;
```

TWebBrowser:

```
procedure TForm2.WebBrowser1ShouldStartLoadWithRequest(ASender: TObject;
  const URL: string);
begin
// check URL and
WebBrowser1.Stop;
end;
```

TTMSFMXWebBrowser:

```
procedure TForm2.TMSFMXWebBrowser1BeforeNavigate(Sender: TObject;
var Params: TTMSFMXCustomWebBrowserBeforeNavigateParams);
begin
// Get your result from Params.URL and cancel via Params.Cancel := True;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try Google before you ask ...

Firemonkey WebBrowser is a wrapper and it depends on platform.

Check this example for TWebBrowser on Windows
http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=1

As WebBrowser is a wrapper, it does not expose all functions.
You have to modify it a little for your purposes.

You can also check these topics
[Callback Delphi function from TWebBrowser by javascript on Delphi XE6 for all platforms (including iOS, ANDROID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416086/callback-delphi-function-from-twebbrowser-by-javascript-on-delphi-xe6-for-all-pl)
http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/adding-javascript-processing-capability-to-twebbrowser-in-ios/