# Delphi and FireMonkey WebBrowser Callback using file://

Tags: javascript, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am using 10.2.2 Tokyo Enterprise and FireMonkey's `TWebBrowser` in an App. I wish to receive a callback response, but I don't receive a URL back when the `ShouldStartLoadWithRequest` fires when I run my code.

I would like to know if this is possible without writing a wrapper. I feel I have missed something simple.

I have checked these sites and many more and have tried many different ways...

[Callback from Firemonkey WebBrowser JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046303/)

[Adding Javascript processing capability to TWebBrowser in iOS](http://delphiworlds.com/2013/11/adding-javascript-processing-capability-to-twebbrowser-in-ios/)

[Callback Delphi function from TWebBrowser by javascript on Delphi XE6 for all platforms (including iOS, ANDROID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416086/)

Here is my simple code version:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<body>
<h2> Get Callback</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

```pascal
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.URL := 'file://' + GetCurrentDir +  '/../../index.html';
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  js : string;
begin
  js := ' var url = "file://' + GetCurrentDir +  '/../../index.html";'+
        'var encodedurl = encodeURIComponent(url);'+
        'window.location.href = encodedurl+"?67";';
  WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript(js);
end;

procedure TForm2.WebBrowser1ShouldStartLoadWithRequest(ASender: TObject;
  const URL: string);
var
  js,TheURL: String;
begin
  TheURL := 'file://' + GetCurrentDir +  '/../../index.html';
  js := URL;
  Fetch(js, TheURL+'?',true,false);  //remove the URL and ?
  js := TIdURI.URLDecode(js, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  Memo1.Lines.Text := js;
end;
```

Changing the end of the URL should, in principle, trick the WebBrowser into believing that it is a new URL, and I should be able to extract the number 67 while still keeping the page refreshed.

Please can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I continued to investigate further ...

Normally when sending a Header to a Server, the Server accepts the Header but in the above instance the Header is sent from a **local URL** **to a local URL**, the browser will picked this up and flag the Header as ill- formed. That is because [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy steps in.

The same-origin request policy can be disabled in Chrome using the --disable-web-security flag. But as I am using the standard Firemonkey Web-browser, the Chrome solution is not fully applicable.

However it seems that the changeable security/zone settings of IE 11 and Edge are completely removed. The only way in which you can access this is via a wrapper.

Refer to [Can the same-origin request policy be disabled in Microsoft Edge?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020612/can-the-same-origin-request-policy-be-disabled-in-microsoft-edge)

Hopefully Embarcadero will add the callback function into the Firemonkey Web browser sometime soon. So in the interim I discovered an easy workaround. I downloaded [ScriptGate 1.0](//https://bitbucket.org/freeonterminate/scriptgate) from the Getit Package Manager and used their wrapper library. Although it is not the real solution to my question, it is a solution for others who are looking for a quick fix.

Here is the callback function that I used to make it happen…

```
uses
SG.ScriptGate,...
 var
    FScriptGate: TScriptGate;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.URL := 'file://' + GetCurrentDir +  '/../../index.html';
  FScriptGate := TScriptGate.Create(Self, WebBrowser1, 'YourOrgScheme');
  end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
//use a timer (set to 200) to call evalfunction if URL not loaded in time 
  evalfunction;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);//callback function
begin
    FScriptGate.CallScript(
    'getvalue()',   // calls the javasacript getvalue function
    procedure(const iResult: String)
    begin
      ShowMessage(iResult); //result will be 67        
  );
end;

procedure TForm2.evalfunction; //populates browser onFormshow
var
 js:string;
begin
    js :=
       'function getvalue(){'+
      ' return "67";'+
       '}';
    WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript(js);
   end;
```