# XE8 Delphi and FireMonkey: Integrating javascript webbrowser and the system

Tags: javascript, delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-xe8

I'm using TWebBrowser component of Delphi to create a system that interacts with the site. So far so good, I can run the website javascript correctly, the problem is when you need to get an answer in Delphi the javascript function in html, I did not find anything to do that. For example, I click a button on Delphi and perform the JS function within the browser, it returns me as True value, I need Delphi take this value in a variable or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback Delphi function from TWebBrowser by javascript on Delphi XE6 for all platforms (including iOS, ANDROID)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416086/callback-delphi-function-from-twebbrowser-by-javascript-on-delphi-xe6-for-all-pl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: used this

[Callback Delphi function from TWebBrowser by javascript on Delphi XE6 for all platforms (including iOS, ANDROID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416086/callback-delphi-function-from-twebbrowser-by-javascript-on-delphi-xe6-for-all-pl)

If anyone knows a better way, feel free to contribute.